# Strategy for Private Fields in Python

Tags: python, field, private

I have the following Python code, which I think emulates a "private" field in the sense that we create a variable that can only accessed by a getter and modified by a setter, not directly discovered.

```
class Foo:
  def __init__( self, value ):
    node = Node( value )
    self.get = lambda : node.get()
    self.set = lambda newValue : node.set( newValue )

class Node:
  def __init__( self, value ):
    self.value = value
  def set( self, value ):
    self.value = value
  def get( self ):
    return self.value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = Foo( 17 )
    print dir(f) #prints __doc__, __init__, __module__, get, set
    print f.get() #prints 17
    f.set(16)
    print f.get() #prints 16
```

Unlike Java, private fields aren't built into Python for various reasons that are discussed in other threads, but I'm wondering what the advantages/disadvantages of using this method of restricting variables are? Are there ways of accessing these "private" variables without using the getting/setting methods?

Obviously, the strategy could be extended well beyond getting and setting if we wanted to model Java private variables and functions, and I understand that this could make for some unwieldy code - let's say that we're not worried about elegance. Is there a name for this type of programming?

Comment: Don't go down this road. If you need to give special behavior to getting and setting a particular name on a Python class, use properties: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

Comment: This type of programming is called "shoehorn driven development". ;)

Comment: Ya, I really don't need to do this at all, I did it by accident in a more complex scenario - I figure it isn't really private, I'm just wondering where my thinking has faltered. And thanks for the name, though nothing pops up when I google that :(

Comment: I think "shoehorn driven development" is tongue in cheek.

Comment: The name is timewasting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A determined user can still get around your defenses by doing

```
f.get.__closure__[0].cell_contents.value
f.get.__closure__[0].cell_contents.value = "some new value"
```

The general disadvantage of programming this way is that all you do is create more work for yourself, and despite all that work you still can't ever really stop anyone from accessing the "private" data.

Comment: Thanks, that does it. Wasn't sure if it was possible to cut through the mess :)